# How to control is there a field for database and have a boolean value

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, parsing, boolean

I parsed my values like that

```
Id = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
Email = fields[1].ToString();
Gid = fields[2].ToString();
SapCompanyCode = fields[3].ToString();
FirstName = fields[4].ToString();
LastName = fields[5].ToString();
FullName = string.Join(" ", FirstName, LastName);
CostCenterName = fields[6].ToString();
ManagerEmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[7]);
ScdDept = fields[8].ToString();
LeaveDate = fields[9] is DBNull ? DateTime.MaxValue : DateTime.Parse(fields[9].ToString());
//StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fields[10].ToString(), Definitions.LongDateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
StartDate = DateTime.Parse(fields[10].ToString());
ContractType = fields[11].ToString();
MonthlyWorkingDay = Convert.ToInt32(fields[12]);
Status = Convert.ToInt32(fields[13]);
LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Parse(fields[14].ToString());
IsSupportStaff = fields[17] is DBNull ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(fields[17]);
```

I have 2 table A and B in SQL. A table update everyday from B table. All of them use same entities. (out of IsSupportStaff and Valid to ValidTo in A table IsSupportStaff in B table. I parsed this value in same Employee cs class but
I have one problem. When I run my code I took an error.Invalid cast from 'DateTime To Boolean'
IsSupportStaff value is a boolean value. and Valid To Value is  DateTime value. and fields 15 expect Valid To and give an error

> Invalid Cast From DateTime To Boolean

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you update your code to include the select clause?

Comment: Attach your full code how you are getting those value